# Comfortable mexican sofa - upload file to specific path

Tags: ruby, content-management-system, comfortable-mexican-sofa

At this moment when I upload file into `CMS` it is being stored in location like:

```
/system/comfy/cms/files/files/000/000/004/original/logo.jpg
```

I would like to be able to specify that `logo` category files will be stored in path

```
/system/logo/logo.jpg
```

and files of category images in:

```
/system/images/image.jpg
```

Where should I start? Im pretty sure that this is impossible to achieve using only `comfy GUI` however I am quite not experienced in working with this `cms`, can anyone give me a hint how I can do that?

Comment: I don't have the answer to this question, but I can tell you that this functionality is controlled by [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).  You can modify the structure in an initializer with something like the following:  ```Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'```

Answer (score 0):

It's right that Paperclip handles that.

However you can set the upload path changing the value of config.upload_file_options entry in the /config/initializers/comfortable_mexican_sofa.rb file

Comment: But from what I have read, change like this will affect all uploads from CMS. I don't want that. I want only change upload path of attachements with specific category (for example attachement of category 'logo')